# How to write a method in Java that averages six positve integers?

Tags: java, methods, integer, average

The method  should average six POSITIVE integers. Integers which are negative or zero should not be included in the average. If all the numbers are invalid return -1. Is there anyway to shorten this code?

```
public float averageSix( int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f ) {
 if( a < 0 ) { a = 0; }
 if( b < 0 ) { b = 0; }
 if( c < 0 ) { c = 0; }
 if( d < 0 ) { d = 0; }
 if( e < 0 ) { e = 0; }
 if( f < 0 ) { f = 0; }
  float aver = ( ( a + b + c + d + e + f ) / ( ( a / a ) + ( b / b ) 
   + ( c / c ) + ( d / d ) + ( e / e ) + ( f / f ) ) );
 if( aver = 0 ) { aver = -1; }
  return aver;
}
```

Comment: 1. Read this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. 2. Logical comparison is '=', not '=='.  3. Negative numbers should be ignored, not assumed as 0. Please, don't divide by 0. 4. Use array instead of 6 numbers.

Comment: Try this:

`public float averageSix( int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f )
{
 int g = 6;
 if( a < 0 ) { g--; }
 if( b < 0 ) { g--; }
 if( c < 0 ) { g--; }
 if( d < 0 ) { g--; }
 if( e < 0 ) { g--; }
 if( f < 0 ) { g--; }
 if(g == 0 ) return -1;
 float aver = ( ( a + b + c + d + e + f ) / g );
 if( aver = 0 ) { aver = -1; }
 return aver;
}`

Comment: (David reaches for his crystal ball) - I see division by zero errors in your future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the code by using [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

This is basically your method trimmed down to use an array.  My calculation only takes into account valid values (ie, if only 3 numbers are valid then I only average the sum by 3), you may need to change this...

```
public float averageSix(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {
    float sum = 0;
    float usedValues = 0;
    int[] values = new int[]{a, b, c, d, e, f};
    for (int value : values) {
        if (value >= 0) {
            usedValues++;
            sum += value;
        }
    }

    float average = -1;
    if (sum > 0) {
        average = sum / usedValues;
    }

    return average;
}
```

nb- As kindly noted by Ted Hopp, the `values` declaration can be shortened to

```
int[] values = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
```

Any thing that saves us having to type any can't hurt ;)

A little more advanced but still valid, you could use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), which allows you to pass in any number of values (not just six)...

```
public float average(int... values) {
    float sum = 0;
    float usedValues = 0;
    for (int value : values) {
        if (value >= 0) {
            usedValues++;
            sum += value;
        }
    }

    float average = -1;
    if (sum > 0) {
        average = sum / usedValues;
    }

    return average;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: `int[] values = new int[]{a, b, c, d, e, f};` can be shortened to `int[] values = {a, b, c, d, e, f};` (the `new int[]` is optional for an array initializer expression).

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks for the comment, I've added into the answer as a side note so it is more highlighted!

Answer (score 4):

```
public float average(int[] numbers) {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++)
      if(numbers[i] > 0) {
          sum += numbers[i];
          count++;
      }

    if(count == 0)
        return -1; // returns -1 if none is greater than 0

    return (float)sum/count;
}
```